# row n was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns: only some rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running the following script to load data from a .csv file on MySQL Workbench:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\movieDB\\movie_metadata_edited.csv"
INTO TABLE IMDB.TITLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
IGNORE 1 LINES

(Title_id, Length, @dummy, Primary_title, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, Language, Country, Content_rating, @dummy, @dummy)
;
```

and it loads just fine *except* for it gives the following warning, for n= 65, 239, 275, 280, 689, 817, 898, 924, 954, 1100, 1216, 1502, 1552, 1776, 1785, 1799, 1847, 1890, 1957, 2035, 2108, 2323, 2371, 2437, 2505, and 2606

> Row n was truncated; it contained more data than there were input
>   columns.

the file I'm trying to load is [movie_metadata.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hs5x2n1x6cm16b/movie_metadata_edited.csv?dl=0), and my table has columns
`Title_id`, `Title_type`, `Primary_title`, `Content_rating`, `Start_year`, `Length`, `Language`, `Country`, `Fancenum_in_poster`.

I found [a solution](http://www.alanjames.org/2009/08/mysql-row-n-was-truncated-a-solution/) for when *every* row comes back with this warning, but no solution was found for when it's only the occasional row.

How can I fix this and get rid of the warning? If I need to fix the file, how to I find each of those rows? The first row in my database doesn't seem to correspond with the first row in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening your file with a text editor, and going to the 66th line (header + 65).

You'll see the `movie_title` is:

> "The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe "

This title includes a comma, which (based on your criteria) means that the above is interpreted as `movie_title` (`"The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion`) and `num_voted_users` (`the Witch and the Wardrobe "`). this will push each of the following columns over by one, leaving you with an extra column in this row.

And, of course, that's not a particularly useful `num_voted_users` value....

However, the solution is already there in the file (for this row at least - presumably for the others). This `.csv` file appears to be formatted so that values that include the column separator are enclosed by double quotes (`"`).

Try running your script with the following modification:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

If MySQL Workbench handles this like most systems I've worked with, it won't assume that *every* value is enclosed by double quotes; however, if a value starts with double quotes, it will ignore column separators until it gets to the closing double quote.

---

Tip: I downloaded your file, opened it in a text editor, and did the following to find lines with problems:

- counted the number of commas in the header line (there were 11);
- using a regular expression search, marked all lines with exactly 11 commas;
- Inverted the marking, so only lines with more or less than 11 commas were marked;
- Looked at the first marked line.

(FYI - I use TextPad as my editor; any good text editor should be able to do something like this, though the details may vary).

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` worked perfectly!